# Caching to make Dashboard faster

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, d3.js, dashboard

I am creating a dashboard using js [backend is hosted on aws]. Can I store the data in indexedDB or localstorage and still make it real-time?

Comment: you need detail more about your dashboard source code

Comment: I am building in d3.. what else info would you need?